# Calling a method of a derived class from base class constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a situation where I'd like each derived instance of `System` to subscribe to an event via my own event system. Basically this means passing a std::function to the event, which is a member field of another instance. So it's basically like this:

```
// System.h
class System
{
    public:
        System(std::shared_ptr<EntityManager> entityManagerPtr);
        virtual ~System();
        virtual void componentAddedEventHandler(void* source, const ComponentAddedEventArgs& args);
    protected:
        std::shared_ptr<EntityManager> m_entityManagerPtr;
};
```

And the implementation, using a delegate:

```
// System.cpp
System::System(std::shared_ptr<EntityManager> entityManagerPtr) : m_entityManagerPtr(entityManagerPtr)
{
    // Subscribe to the componentAddedEvent
    m_entityManagerPtr->componentAddedEvent += [&](void* source, ComponentAddedEventArgs args) {
        this->componentAddedEventHandler(source, args);
    };
}
```

But obviously this won't compile without defining `System::componentAddedEventHandler()`.

**What would be the best way to ensure that each class derived from `System` would subscribe to the event, and they all would have to define their own implementation for the event handler? Or is it just too inconvenient to force such behavior, so that it should be achieved in some other way?**

Comment: Yes, I did find some discussion regarding the topic, but it didn't really answer my question. The way I see it, this kind of behavior is not possible without a) two phase initialization or b) some helper classes. I'd like to be proven wrong in this case, by which I mean that there could be a more elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you're actually trying to do?  Right now my gut says you're way over-thinking this.

Comment: dont abuse your object model... if the base class needs to do something, implement it there.

Comment: `class System`?  Wow.  I really hope you're not on windows of any flavor.  Why not just use an abstract virtual method in the base class?  (Of course, delegates could do the same thing, but not with strong contract enforcement)

Comment: @MichaelKristofik I was thinking I'd like to have all classes derived from `System` to subscribe to an event, and to be forced to implement their own handler for said event. Now that I've rethought the issue a bit, it doesn't seem all that important in my case, but still stands as an intriguing problem. The point in this case was to implement a sort of cache refresh whenever a new `Component` is added to any `Entity` in the `EntityManager`. But I guess it should be left for the derived classes to worry about their cache.

Comment: @GradyPlayer actually it isn't the base class that needs to do something in this case, but rather the derived class. But, as I mentioned above, I don't actually think this sort of behavior is so important anymore.

Comment: @ebyrob Nope, no Windows here. If I declare the event handler method as an abstract virtual method, I don't think it will fix the issue at hand, as it is being called from the constructor of the base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP said in a comment (empahsis mine):

> I was thinking I'd like to have **all classes derived from `System`** to subscribe to an event, and to **be forced to** implement their own handler for said event.

"All classes derived from X" and "be forced to" in the same sentence screams for a pure virtual member function.

```
struct System
{
     virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct Subsystem : public System
{
     virtual void foo() override { /* forced to implement this */ }
};
```

If you store your Systems by smart pointer (in a container perhaps), you can call `foo()` for each one and be assured to get the dervied class' behavior.

This is all fine, but you can't call `foo()` from the base class' constructor.  A low-tech solution to this problem is to use a factory function to construct each object.

```
template <typename T>
unique_ptr<T> make_system()
{
    auto obj = make_unique<T>();
    obj->foo();
    return obj;
}

auto s1 = make_system<Subsystem1>();
auto s2 = make_system<Subsystem2>();
```

Both of these objects are forced to implement `foo()` and both objects have called `foo()` prior to being used.  This is still two-phase initialization, but it's hidden for you behind a function call.

Comment: Yes, but that's half of the problem solved: I can force the derived classes to implement the event handler, but not to subscribe to the event.

Comment: @vijoc `m_entityManagerPtr->componentAddedEvent += foo;` ?  Note: Sorry for not "screaming" when I mentioned abstract virtuals...  You can do that in the constructor.  (Or were you worried they'd skip the base class' constructor?) A factory might be more forceful.

Comment: Is it really that simple? If I pass the lambda calling an abstract virtual method (in the constructor of the base class), it will compile and do what I hope it will, i.e. call the method of the derived class?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're into undefined behavior territory if you call a function on an object (the derived part in this case) that doesn't exist.  However, it might be ok to store a lambda that might call it later, after it's been fully constructed.

Comment: @vijoc - you actually **can't** force derived classes to implement the event handler. `struct Base { virtual void f() = 0; }; struct Intermediate : Base { void f() { } }; struct Derived : Intermediate { }; Derived d;` There's no problem creating objects of type `Derived` even though it does not provide it's own version of `f`.

Comment: Food for thought I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872707/calling-a-method-in-constructor of course stuffing foo into an event model really isn't the same as actually calling it.  (Then again it could get called multi-threaded) Gotta be sure to remove it if constructor fails too.

Comment: What about the OP's lambda-based solution, but moved into the base class constructor?  The lambda itself is in the base class, but when it's called, shouldn't it call the sub-class's implementation virtually through the `this` pointer?  The only thing to worry about then is that you may have a race condition if it is called immediately (before the object is done constructing), and that of course could be very bad, but there may be other ways to guarantee that not happening.  That being said, I agree with the factory solution too.  It works.

Comment: @PeteBecker Actually that won't be a problem, as it is not my intention to have inheritance deeper than one level. Also, I've rethought the problem and I'm not sure I need to force such behavior on all derived classes, but rather offer it as an option (say, have a protected method the derived classes can then call in their constructors for example). Still, I'm going to investigate what on earth happens if that function call is stored in a lambda in the base class constructor.